# Which Phrase is more appropriate?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, email

Here is a bit of context.. I will be proactively emailing a few of our users asking if they are facing any issues using the application.

Which is more appropriate / gramatically correct phrase in this context?

> **If you face any issue then let me know.** OR **Let me know if you face any
>   issues.**

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: They both sound pretty informal - is this the tone you want to give?
p.s. thank you for the contest, or I would not have asked this.

Comment: Yeah .. I know that it is an informal tone but does it sound unprofessional? I am not a native English speaker so sometimes I have a hard time differentiating between "informal" and "unprofessional"

Comment: Very good point!
I've seen it used like this on social network websites, internet companies, hip and "young" places that want a direct contact with their users, and it is not unprofessional to me, because the people behind them are probably not much older than I am. 

If I were older, if I were a professor, or if large commercial software companies like MATLAB wrote me like this, I'd find it unprofessional. Everything depends on your audience, what they expect from you and how you already wrote them! If you suddenly switch from formal to informal or viceversa, they will not like it.

Comment: @writingthesis.. Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation..Highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are completely acceptable, except "issue" should be plural in the first sentence. Switching the clauses like you did is allowed, and I've used both of those structures interchangeably.